# Taking ownership from a smart pointer with further access to the raw pointer via the same smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a leaky code like this:

```
void f() {
  SomeClass *sc = new SomeClass;
  ...
  if (...) {
    g(sc); // g() takes ownership of memory pointed to by sc
  }
  ...
  sc->SomeMethod();
  ...
}
```

I'd like to eliminate leaks by using smart pointers, thought of the following solution:

```
void f() {
  smart_ptr<SomeClass> sc(new SomeClass);
  ...
  if (...) {
    g(sc.release()); // ownership is taken
  }
  ...
  sc->SomeMethod(); // sc points to the allocated memory regardless of whether ownership was taken or not
  ...
} // the memory is freed if ownership was not taken
```

Tried to use std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr. std::unique_ptr points to the null pointer after release, std::shared_ptr has no release() at all. Manual increase of reference counter of std::shared_ptr would have helped, but as I understand correctly there is no such an ability too.

Thought of using std::unique_ptr in addition to the raw pointer leaving the code as is and just calling release() each time the raw pointer is passed to the function that takes ownership, but it is a very muddy solution.

I wonder if there is a smart pointer from the standard library that fit for my goals,
or maybe there is an ideom or common trick how to do in my case or may I missing something?

Comment: Just use a `unique_ptr` and a raw pointer, it's the simplest solution. You do need to ensure that `g()` doesn't `delete` the object before you call `SomeMethod()` via the raw pointer.

Comment: Yes, the solution is simplest but error-prone. The code is open source, I'd like to use a single variable. The real body of `f()` is large, the pointer is frequently used and the ownership is transferred several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retain a local, non-owning view with just a little more code:

```
void g(std::unique_ptr<Foo> p);     // takes ownership

int main()
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    Foo & local_view = *p;

    if (/* condition */) { g(std::move(p)); }

    local_view.do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the clearest and best solution.  When you start using `release()`, the ownership becomes much harder to follow, and it becomes easy to accidentally defeat the exception safety that you got by using `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to first define the smart pointer and then make the local view from it, this is more correct than define the raw pointer and then create the unique_ptr wrapper as I tried. But I wouldn't like to use several variables for a single entity - the code is open source and the real body of f() is large, ownership is transferred in several places and the pointer is frequently used, the solution seems error-prone to me.

Comment: Apparently it is the best solution unless the desired smart pointer exist. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if `g()` does not store `p` somewhere? As long as `g()` has exclusive ownership, `local_view` could very well be a dangling reference when it is time to `do_stuff()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shared_ptr` with equal effect. `shared_ptr` does not have a `release()` function but it has a `reset()` function, which is what I think you are looking for. However, you have to wait until after the call to `SomeClass::SomeMethod()` to call `sc.reset()`.

```
void g(shared_ptr<SomeClass> ptr);

void f()
{
   shared_ptr<SomeClass> sc(new SomeClass);

   if (/* check for condition */)
   {
      g(sc);
   }

   sc->SomeMethod();
   sc.reset();
}
```

Comment: Use of shared pointers should be considered carefully; they are often an indicator of poorly thought out data structures, and have more overhead than a `unique_ptr` since they must be thread-safe.  Even if `g` really does need a `shared_ptr`, `sc` doesn't need to be a `shared_ptr`.  `unique_ptr` is implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr` (though you would need to change `g(sc)` to `g(std::move(sc))`).  This way, you only incur the `shared_ptr` overhead when `g()` is actually called.

Comment: Also, `sc.reset()` is unnecessary since `sc` is being destroyed immediately afterwards anyway.

Comment: Note if you change `sc` to a `unique_ptr` you also should use the local view technique described by KerrekSB above.

Comment: Yes, `sc.reset()` seem to be unnecessary here. One more note: `g` is declared as `g(SomeClass *)` and I can't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean about `g` taking ownership, because after `g` exits you are still going to use the pointer. If you always want to use the pointer after `g`, it makes more sense to pass a raw pointer to `g` and deallocate the pointer at the end of the block.

If you do want `g` to take ownership, and want to call the `SomeMethod` only if your pointer still exists, pass a raw pointer to `g` and have it return a raw pointer. If the pointer gets deallocated in `g`, return `nullptr` and check for that before the `SomeMethod` call.

Comment: `g` stores the row pointer to the storage for the further processing, the storage cares about the deletion of it's contents at the end of execution. I can't edit implementation of `g`.

Answer (score -1):

> `g() takes ownership of memory pointed to by sc`

This is a blocker for your stated plan. Since `g()` owns the memory, it is allowed to release that memory before you get around to calling `sc->SomeMethod()`, which would lead to undefined behavior.

A simple and safe solution could be to change `g()` to accept a `shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer, so that the caller can share ownership. To preserve existing call sites, you could at the same time introduce an overload of `g()` that takes a raw pointer, constructs a `shared_ptr` from it, then calls the version taking a `shared_ptr`.

```cpp
void g(SomeClass *sc) {
    // Forward processing to the overload
    g(std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>(sc));
}
```

A more involved solution might involve asking the new owner of the memory to call `SomeMethod` for you. (Create a flag to track whether or not you own the memory?) Because that memory is no longer yours to access. What you are doing is like buying a car, giving it to someone, then sneaking in to take the car for a drive. That's theft. You gave the car away, so it is no longer yours. You gave the memory away, so it is no longer yours.

```cpp
using SomeHandle = /* a way to access an object stored by g() */
SomeHandle g(SomeClass *sc) {
    // Do stuff
    SomeHandle handle = /* Transfer ownership of sc to storage */
    // Do more stuff?
    return handle;
}
```

The best solution is probably to take a step or two back in your design and re-evaluate. Sometimes reorganizing code to take a different approach makes this sort of situation disappear, as if by magic. Especially if the real body of `f()` is large and complicated. (Keep your functions simple and focused on a single task.)